# How to add a 100vh header image on a page with a height of 100Vh?

Tags: html, css

I have a page wrapped in a container that has a 100vh height. I need this in order to be able to vertically center the content of the other pages later.

However, on the homepage, I can't add a header with a 100vh background image anymore because of this.

I could do hacky stuff with javascript such as "if you are on homepage, height is 100% else it's 100vh" but it's quite ugly and I'd prefer to handle it with pure css.

How to do it?

Here is the code:

html:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header/>
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <div className="content">
          <h3>content</h3>
        </div>
        <footer>footer</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

css:

```js
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  padding: 24px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVHPI0EekAVTf_xKei3cwTsvvi3PChxaXeIA&usqp=CAU");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  padding: 24px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is also a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wright-c85gi?file=/src/App.js:24-287

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  height:100vh;
}
```